# Apply Style to entire row in python pandas based on the value returned after a if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue']}, 
              columns=['numbers', 'colors'])


def flag():
background: "Yellow"


for i in df.index:
#1. If colors = red  and number < 2
if ('red' in df['colors'][i]) and (df['numbers'][i] < 2):
    v = df['colors'][i]
    df.style.apply(flag)
```

I am trying to use whatever comes out of that if statement to highlight the entire row save the data frame. write another if statement update the dataframe again and so on and eventually write that dataframe on excel sheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wtMH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not correct:

1. 'background:"Yellow"' is not a valid css style
2. You should apply `flag` on row, so `flag` should accept a row argument

Here's a fix:

```
def flag(x):
    if x['numbers']<2 and 'red' in x['colors']:
        s = 'background: yellow'  
    else: 
        s = ''
    return [s]*len(x)

# style apply
df.style.apply(flag, axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. one more question is there a way to write a highlight function and call it after every if statement in case there are 100's of if statements

Comment: You should think of all the possible if statements/formats and put them inside the flag function.